# Помогите найти ошибку в вычислении суммы (java)

Tags: java, операторы

[image: сум]

```
public class TaskB {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    

Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
double x = scanner.nextDouble();
double y=0;
    for(double i=x-1; i<=6; i++){
        double a=0;
        while (a<=2) {
            a = a + 0.2;
            y=y+Math.pow(7, a) - Math.cos(x);
            System.out.printf("При а=%6.2f x=%6.2f Сумма y=%g\n", a, x, y);

        }

    }
```

}
}

```
Тест пишет:
Ожидается:
При a=0,00 Сумма y = 6,****48e+00
При a=0,20 Сумма y = 9,****87e+00
При a=0,40 Сумма y = 1,****09e+01
При a=0,60 Сумма y = 1,****22e+01
При a=0,80 Сумма y = 2,****31e+01
При a=1,00 Сумма y = 4,****65e+01
При a=1,20 Сумма y = 6,****12e+01
При a=1,40 Сумма y = 9,****72e+01
При a=1,60 Сумма y = 1,****77e+02
При a=1,80 Сумма y = 1,****33e+02
При a=2,00 Сумма y = 2,****56e+02
```

Comment: Что это за огрызок кода, и почему Вы думаете, что в нем есть ошибка (одна?)?

Comment: я не добавил только psvm вверху

Comment: Что это значит?

Comment: добавил весь код

Comment: ...и почему Вы думаете, что в нем есть ошибка?

Comment: мне кажется, я неправильно  понял символ суммы, тест выдает вот что:Ожидается:
При a=0,00 Сумма y = 6,****48e+00
При a=0,20 Сумма y = 9,****87e+00

Comment: В вопрос, всё в вопрос.

Comment: Не нужно складывать результаты для разных a. x тоже дан, зачем вы его запрашиваете?

Comment: черт, спасибо, зрение настолько упало, что думал, что там x-1

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из условия, предполагаю что нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
public class TaskB {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    for(double a = 0; a <= 2.0; a += 0.2d){
    double y=0;
        for(int x = 1; x <= 6; x++){
                y += Math.pow(7, a) - Math.cos(x);
        }
        System.out.printf("При а=%.2f Сумма y = %f\n", a, y);
    }
}
}
```

При этом в задаче не вижу ничего что требовало бы пользовательского ввода. Может я не правильно понял задачу? хм...

Ну и в ожидаемом выводе не совсем понятен последний элемент